# How to stop codeigniter 4 from cashing webpage

Tags: codeigniter, caching, cache-control, codeigniter-4

Please I want to totally stop cache in my codeigniter 4 project. It caches some of my webpage without instructing it to. I have use the below code but did not achieve my aim:

```
  $cache = \Config\Services::cache();

           $cache->clean();
```

It is frustrating when the site caches another user's account and enabling the entire members to see someone's account. I don't know if am the only one experiencing this or global issue... PLEASE I NEED HELP.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your app/Config/cache.php file and didn't change anything there then your cache handler should still be "file". If that is the case and you didn't load your cache service anywhere in your app then codeigniter will not cache anything.

Actually, if you open your writable/cache folder that should be empty too.

Although if you are in fact caching something in your app and want to remove the cache data that should be the correct way of doing it.

This method will ‘clean’ the entire cache. If the deletion of the cache files fails, the method will return FALSE.

If you're not sure on what cache is being saved or how, you can also check that by using the cache_info method.

```
cache_info()
Returns:    Information on the entire cache database
Return type:    mixed
```

This method will return information on the entire cache.

Example:

```
var_dump($cache->getCacheInfo());
```

If  there's actually no cache being used you might want to look into your sessions, your problem might come from there.

Comment: The cache folder is empty. 

I get this error: **Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Cache\Handlers\FileHandler::cache_info()**

using:

`$cache = \Config\Services::cache();
var_dump($cache->cache_info());`

Comment: changed the post to getCacheInfo looks like the docs are still pointing to an old function. But if the cache folder is empty then codeigniter is not caching anything. Your might be using some other cache system on your server that you haven't identified.

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: If your config says file handler and the folder is empty, then codeigniter is not caching anything. Then its something else outside your app. Something like apache (if that's what you're using to run the app) I never used it but I know apache has a mod_cache that can be enabled.

Comment: it is not a server issue because I changed server recently.

Comment: perhaps, the cache folder is empty.

Comment: Are you sure the issue you're experience is from cache? Might be something in the sessions.

Comment: I once suspected the session... what can make session behave abnormal like this?

Comment: I have been trying to fix the issue from the session aspect for the past 3 months up to no avail before I started thinking that it might be cache.

Comment: Is your problem something like this: User1 Logs in, starts to use the app, after a while his name changes to another user and he starts to see the other user account? If so, you might just check my answer as correct since its not a cache problem. Create a new thread with the #codeigniter-4 tag and in there put the code on how you're checking if the user is logged in and after that the code on how you're getting the logged user data. Also show how you are destroying the user session when he logs out. When you create that new thread just ping me here and I'll look into it.

Comment: exactly, that's the issue. okay I will do as you said.